# General minimum vertex cover of a hypercube

Tags: graph-theory

Let the size of minimum vertex cover be $\tau(G)$ for a graph $G$.

For the hypercube $Q_2$, $\tau(Q_2)=2$.
To form the next hypercube, say $Q_3$, we clone $Q_2$ (along with its vertex cover), then connect vertices between the clones so that the new edges are covered by exactly one vertex from the vertex cover. And so on.

This way, every successive $Q_k$ has $\tau(Q_k)=2\tau(Q_{k-1})$.

Using this reasoning, is it right to say that $\tau(Q_k)=2^{k-1}$?

Comment: definition of cover number: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexCover.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tau(Q_n)$ is indeed equal to $2^{n-1}$, but your construction of a vertex cover of that size only provides an upper bound. To prove that $2^{n-1}$ is also a lower bound, note that each vertex is incident to $n$ edges and that a hypercube has $n2^{n-1}$ edges, so at least $2^{n-1}$ vertices are required for the cover.